# How to create a barplot with several variable

Tags: r

I am very new to R and I am trying to create a barplot with my infiltration on the y axis and burn on the x axis comparing the grazing treatment (example of the data set is below)

```
Infiltration    Grazing Burn
3301.145496 G   S
8165.771889 U   S
9937.833576 G   L
11576.5892  U   L
32739.07643 G   N
25923.84328 U   N
25942.3     G   C
```

So far I have produced the code so that it reads the table

```
   #reads the basic data in
   ana<-read.table("D:\\Dave.txt",head=T)
   attach(ana)
   head(ana)
   dim(ana)
```

However I do  not understand how to write the code to produce a barplot.

I have attached an image of how I produced the graph on excel 
[excel graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6n1Zg.png)

Also I do not have the ggplot, how do I format it as "barplot(....."

Comment: Also I do not know how to format the data I added add the top into  table - I am aware it reads terribly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your dataset and assuming 'ana$burn' is coded as a factor:

```
barplot(xtabs(ana$Infiltration ~ ana$Burn + ana$Grazing),beside = TRUE)
```

The beside = TRUE gives your barplot side by side, if you want to stack, put beside = FALSE (just look at the two, see what you prefer).

If 'ana$Burn' and 'ana$Grazing' not coded as factor, you need to add this before:

```
ana$Burn = as.factor(ana$Burn)
ana$Grazing = as.factor(ana$Grazing)
```

Comment: thank you. This works however only plots the burn, how do I go about adding the grazing treatment on the barplot ?

Comment: I edited my answer. See if it works for you and accept it if that's the case

Answer (score 1):

With the sample dataset available, an example could be:

```
barplot(as.matrix(mtcars[,10:11]), beside = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: what does the [10:11] mean?

Comment: This is matrix notation. [,10:11] means columns 10 to 11 ([10:11,] would mean rows 10 to 11. with the mtcars dataset this means mtcars$gear and mtcars$carb

Comment: I still do not understand how to write this in the format of my own data